# sourceforge checksums: Where are they?

Tags: security, checksum, sourceforge

I've been particular about checksumming all downloaded software.  Today, trying to download from Sourceforge, I could not find any checksums for the projects.  Am I just missing them or are they not there?  How do others verify checksums from softwared downloaded from sourceforge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the **Files** page of a project, for example:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/httpfs/files/

Next to each file there is an "i" icon. Click on it for the checksums.

[image: checksums]

Comment: sure enough.  there they are.  Thank you.  sometimes you have to drill down into the project to find the actual files.